# Initializing a View controller using initWithNibName

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        fetched = NO;
        self.title = @"Nearby";
        // Custom initialization

        liked = NO;

        categories = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        fundings = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        stages = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }


    return self;
}
```

I use the code above. am I during anything wrong by initializing all of my varialbes in the initWithNibName function? Is that the correct place to do so?

Comment: Are you having an actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably not run into issues, but you can use a ViewController also with the pure `init` in which case the NIB is not loaded and also your initialization will not be called. Another place to make the init for that is the `viewDidLoad` which is called only after the init.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the `init` method, that's fine. You could also do it (or some of) in the `viewDidLoad` method. The difference would (generally) be that `viewDidLoad` is called when your view is actually getting ready to be shown, so you need everything setup. `init` on the other hand could be called well in advance. There isn't a hard and fast answer, it depends what the items you're setting up are and if they can be unloaded when the view isn't on display. With newer versions of iOS that concern changes anyway as the view generally isn't unloaded. You really need to read about the view and controller life cycles and decide when to create and destroy your attributes.